# How do I set default value using ng-select in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have my code in HTML like this.

```html
      <div class="col-md-10">
          <ng-select [items]="tests" (data)="updateSelected($event, 'test')">

          </ng-select>
       </div>
```

My typescript code is as follows

```js
@Input() tests: Option[] = []; I have tests coming as input from previous component

     @ViewChildren(SelectComponent)
     private selectComponents: QueryList<SelectComponent>;
    
    ngAfterViewInit() {
            this.selectComponents;
        }
```

How do I set some value as default value here in selectComponents or is there any other way to set some value as default value using ng-select.

Comment: What's​ `ng-select`? If it's a lib, please provide link.

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/

Answer (score 3):

Use ngModel binding as below.

```
<ng-select options="users" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
</select>
```

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedValue = ["1"]
}
```

Array item value is option id. https://basvandenberg.github.io/ng-select may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Reactive forms, you can bind the value while creating `FormGroup`.
```

In TS:

```
 import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

 accountForm: FormGroup; // declaring form group


constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {} 

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
}

createForm(): void {
    this.accountForm = this.fb.group({
       trial: ['Yes', [Validators.required]] // Its default value
    });
  }
```

In case, if the value is dynamic (eg. from API call), you can set it with
`this.accountForm.patchValue({trial: 'abcd'});`

In HTML:

```
<form class="form"
    [formGroup]="accountForm"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(accountForm)"
    autocomplete="off"
    novalidate>
    <div  class="form-row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" >
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Trial</label>
      <ng-select
         [items]="booleanDropdown"
         [multiple]="false"
         [selectableGroup]="true"
         [closeOnSelect]="true"
         [clearable]="false"
         formControlName="trial">
      </ng-select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either define a component type object for the variable or or you can get the first element of the list and set it as a defualt variable.

```
    @ViewChildren(SelectComponent) private selectComponents: QueryList<SelectComponent>;
defualtComponent: any; ngAfterViewInit() { this.defaultComponent = this.selectComponents.get(0); }
```

This will select the first element if that is what you want as ypur default element.

Comment: what does this.defaultComponent = this.selectComponents;  do?

Comment: Updated just now.

Comment: this.defaultComponent = this.selectComponents.get(0), this will set the whole of the first object in selectComponent as active. I want the first item object in the first object to be set to active.